# Emscripten SDK error on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: javascript, macos, ecmascript-6, emscripten, webassembly

Tried to install the Emscripten SDK on **Mac OS X Sierra version 10.12.5**

[Followed these steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm#Compiling_Emscripten)

Tried on both **Python versions  3.6.2 and 2.7.13**

**I am getting an error log in my terminal window as below:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./emsdk", line 35, in 
>   if os.name == 'nt' or 'WINDOWS' in os.getenv('SYSTEMROOT') or 'WINDOWS' in os.getenv('COMSPEC'):
>   TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

**Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a regression  bug as stated by author. **Now fixed**.

For More details visit [github issue](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/5475)